# LINQ reuse "where" filter on a specific type

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I'm working on a task where I need to reuse a filter method in the where clause of LINQ statement.

Here is how the data is structured (like a NoSQL database).

```
Collection name: Customer 
Name: Name1, Type: Type1
Name: Name2, Type: Type2
Name: Name3, Type: Type1

Collection name: Comments
Comment: MyComment1, Customer:{Name: Name2, Type: Type2}
Comment: MyComment2, Customer:{Name: Name1, Type: Type1}
Comment: MyComment3, Customer:{Name: Name1, Type: Type1}
```

Here is my method to get filtered results from the Customer collection.

```
public static IQueryable<Customer> customersWhere(IQueryable<Customer> customerWhere, string customerType)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerType))
        customerWhere = customerWhere.Where(c => c.type == customerType);

    return customerWhere;

}
```

Here is how I use the above method to get me filtered results from the customer collection.

```
//customer filter
string customerType = "Type1";

var customersResult = customers.Select(c => c).AsQueryable();

//filtered result for customer
customersResult = customersWhere(customersResult, customerType);
```

With the above statement, I get results (customers with Name1 and Name2)

When I work on the comments collection, if I like to filter the comments by customer type, I'd like to reuse the "customerWhere" method on the comment.Customer object. Here is how I attempted to reuse this method.

```
//pull customer comment. 
var commentsResult = comments.Select(c => c).AsQueryable();

//filtered comments by customer type
//I'd like to reuse my customersWhere method here.
commentsResult = commentsResult.Where(c => c.customer == 
customersWhere((IQueryable<Customer>)c.customer, customerType));
```

I was expecting to get MyComment2 and MyComment3 in the result. But I keep on getting ""Unable to cast object of type 'Customer' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ConsoleApp1.Program+Customer]'.""

How will I be able to reuse the filter method on any collection having the customer object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to make your "customersWhere()" method generic so that you can use it in any condition. pass an expression as a parameter instead of customerType. Use delegate here.

```
    public static IQueryable<T> customersWhere<T>(IQueryable<T> 
    customerWhere, 
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
       customerWhere = customerWhere.Where(predicate);
        return customerWhere;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>()
       {
           new Customer(){name="Name1", type ="Type1"},
           new Customer(){name="Name2", type ="Type2"},
           new Customer(){name="Name2", type ="Type1"}
       };

        List<CustomerWithComment> customerWithComment = new List<CustomerWithComment>()
       {
           new CustomerWithComment(){comment = "Customer1", customer = new Customer(){name="Name2", type ="Type2"}},
           new CustomerWithComment(){comment = "Customer2", customer = new Customer(){name="Name1", type ="Type1"}},
           new CustomerWithComment(){comment = "Customer3", customer = new Customer(){name="Name1", type ="Type1"}}
       };

        string customerType = "Type1";

        Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> predicate = i => i.type ==customerType;
        var listcustomer = customers.Select(c => c).AsQueryable();
        listcustomer = customersWhere<Customer>(listcustomer, predicate);

        Expression<Func<CustomerWithComment, bool>> customerWithCommentExpression = i => i.customer.type ==customerType;
        var commentsResult = customerWithComment.Select(c => c).AsQueryable();
        commentsResult = customersWhere<CustomerWithComment>(commentsResult, customerWithCommentExpression);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

class used

```
    public class Customer
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerWithComment
    {
        public string comment { get; set; }
        public Customer customer { get; set; }
    }
```

It is working fine as I tested. Hope it would help you and you will get expected output

Comment: If you want to reuse method so better to make it generic

Answer (score 1):

Within this line you're trying to cast `Customer` (I believe `Comment` has only one `Customer`) to `IQueryable<Customer>`

```
commentsResult = commentsResult.Where(c => c.customer == customersWhere((IQueryable<Customer>)c.customer, customerType));
```

If you want to reuse your method. Consider exposing public method for validating single `Customer`. Like so (you can also use it in your original method):

```
public static IQueryable<Customer> CustomersWhere(IQueryable<Customer> customers, string customerType)
{
    return customers.Where(c => CustomerWhere( c, customerType ));
}

public static bool CustomerWhere( Customer customer, string customerType )
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerType))
    {
        return customer.Type == customerType ;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And usage:

```
const string customerType = "Type1";
var comments = new Comment[]
    {
        new Comment(),
        new Comment(),
        new Comment {Customer = new Customer()}
    }.AsQueryable();

var customersResult = comments.Select(c => c.Customer).AsQueryable();
customersResult = CustomersWhere(customersResult, customerType);

var commentsResult = comments.Select(c => c).AsQueryable();
commentsResult = commentsResult.Where(c => CustomerWhere( c.Customer, customerType ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have the result in `customersResult` and you need to reuse it instead of calling the method again:

```
commentsResult = commentsResult.Where(c1 => customersResult.Any(c2 => c.customer == c2));
```